# How to check for open comm ports win 7?

Tags: ports

How to get open comm ports serial or parallel in windows 7 system? I have a java program that needs to send a request through that port but I am unable to detect the open port.

Need help

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the port using CreateFile. If the will return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then GetLastError will return the corresponding error code (port already opened).

```
CreateFile(ComName,                   {name like COM}
       GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, {access attributes}
       0,                             {no sharing}
       nil,                           {no security}
       OPEN_EXISTING,                 {creation action}
       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL or
       FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,          {attributes}
       0);                            {no template}
```